# Don't work plugins ChildBrowser with Phonegap 1.9.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

Don't work plugins ChildBrowser (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) with Phonegap 1.9.0 (using android version). 
There are some errors in ChildBrowser.java.
javascript write that window.plugins is deprecated.

Have some one any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had posted up an upgraded [ChildBrowser.java](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/887989/ChildBrowser.java) that works with 1.9.0 to my Dropbox account. I haven't pushed the changes to github as I want to make it so that in 2.0.0 you don't need to update your plugins src code just to have them work in the latest version of PG. I hope to check in that change before 2.0.0 is released so we can all move forward with good instructions on how to upgrade your plugins.

Just as a follow up, here is my blog post on the kerfuffle.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/phonegap-android-plugins-sometimes-we.html

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to make it work with Cordova 1.9.0 with few changes in the `ChildBrowser.java` file.

Changes I have done:

- `ctx.getContext()` replaced with `ctx.getActivity().getApplicationContext()`
- `ctx.startActivity()` replaced with `ctx.getActivity().startActivity()`
- `ctx.getSystemService()` replaced with `ctx.getActivity().getSystemService()`
- `ctx.getAssets()` replaced with `ctx.getActivity().getAssets()`
- `ctx.runOnUiThread()` replaced with `ctx.getActivity().runOnUiThread()`
- `new Dialog(ctx.getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar)` replaced with `new Dialog(ctx.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar)`

I have not tested aggressively but it does work with basic tests. I might have replaced something wrong or missed anything but the above changes are working fine.

Full source at - https://gist.github.com/3085079

I have tested with Cordova 1.9 on Android 2.2

Comment: bhai In first one only `ctx` is enough, instead of `ctx.getContext()`  :)..Although +1 for such details....

Comment: @Coder_sLaY thanks, didn't realize that part. put detail in case required for other plugin.